# Why does my visit counter keep resetting?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've been visiting the Retrocomputing site every day for over 60 days. On three occasions the visit count has falsely reset to 1 visit.

The counter seems to be rather buggy! or is someone just screwing with me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two things that trip people up are:

1. UTC time, and
2. [What actions count as access.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/1438)

The second is purposefully a bit vague, but just visiting the home page doesn't count. You need to read a question or some other action that demonstrates you are using the site in some capacity.

The first is mostly a problem if you aren't on a regular schedule. Weekends are especially tricky for me in California since I might log out on Friday afternoon before the end of the UTC day and not come back until Saturday evening. Even though I've been to the site on two consecutive *localtime days*, I've missed a UTC day.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR: It's not a bug, it's a feature.

[This might be caused by caching](//shouldiblamecaching.com/). A good tip when trying for the [[• Enthusiast]](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54) badge is to perform an *action* every day (voting, asking, answering, etc.) to ensure that your browser isn't caching the homepage and is actually making a request to the Stack Exchange servers. This also has the added benefit of getting you used to contributing (arguably the intention of the badge); I see from your profile that there are things that you know that you haven't shared yet.

There is also the possibility that you actually *did* miss a day. I had done this on two separate occasions whilst trying for the [[• Fanatic]](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) badge. This is even easier when your time-zone is not UTC, because visiting in the morning one day and the evening the next can result in having skipped a UTC day. To prevent this, you could visit in the morning *and* the evening.

These badges are really, really hard to get. That's why they're silver and gold, not bronze and silver. So, don't feel too bad when this happens; it's annoying but will make victory even sweeter.